# How to make my second inline-block not start at the bottom of the previous one without using floats?

Tags: html, css

i want my second inline-block to start at the top and not below the previous one without using float

```
<body>  
  <div class="adleft">
    left part
  </div> 
  <div class="main"> second part</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
  div.adleft {
   display: inline-block;
   /* float: left; */
   background: yellow;
   margin: 0;
   width: 40px;
   /* overflow:auto; */
 }

 div.main {
   display: inline-block;
   background: olive;
   margin: -5px;
   width: 400px
   /* float:left; */
 }
```

this is what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/xkwztvj2/1/

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add vertical-align: top; to div.main